# adding classes to HTML

Tags: html, class, attributes, tags

in some where of my html coding that is wanted to add another attribute beside of the ex-one

{The bottom borders under your % Daily Value * and Saturated Fat 1g 5% elements do not extend the full width of the label. Add no-divider to the class for these two elements. Your p element with the text Saturated Fat 1g 5% should have no-divider added to the class attribute. Do not remove the existing classes.}

```
<div class="daily-value sm-text">
        <p class="right bold"  >% Daily Value *</p>
        <div class="no-divider"></div>
        <p><span class="bold">Total Fat</span> 8g<span class="bold right">10%</span></p>
        <p class="indent">Saturated Fat 1g <span class="bold right">5%</span></p>
      </div>
```

\

Answer (score 0):

To add the no-divider class to the p element with the text "Saturated Fat 1g 5%", you can modify the HTML code as follows:

```
<div class="daily-value sm-text">
        <p class="right bold"  >% Daily Value *</p>
        <div class="no-divider"></div>
        <p><span class="bold">Total Fat</span> 8g<span class="bold right">10%</span></p>
        <p class="indent no-divider">Saturated Fat 1g <span class="bold right">5%</span></p>
      </div>
```

The no-divider class should be added to the class attribute of the p element, separated by a space from the existing indent class. This will add the no-divider class to the element, allowing you to apply the desired styling to it.

Answer (score 0):

Needed to add new classes to an existing class, this code worked for me:

```
<div class="daily-value small-text">
  <p class="bold right no-divider">% Daily Value *</p>
  <div class="divider"></div>
  <p><span><span class="bold">Total Fat</span> 8g</span> <span class="bold">10%</span></p>
  <p class="indent no-divider">Saturated Fat 1g <span class="bold">5%</span></p>
</div>
```